# Set one session per user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I ned to set a session per every user, so when the user log ou from his account and login again in another account the old session will not be shown but the new that related to his new account will be shown

I am using the normal method in laravel to do it

Session::put('key', 'value');

But the problem as explained is that the session will br shown in all user using this computer

Comment: Just unset/destroy the session when they click on "log out".

Comment: @ShadyHesam There is absolutely no need for that. Set a logout button that send a request to your controller. Then in your controller, you simply use ```Auth::logout()```

Answer (score 0):

Session ids are supposed to be non-guessable. You're going to have to resolve (attempted) duplicates serverside. If you search through every existing session for a match then your not going to be able to scale this / its going to be very slow. That means you need an access path to the session data based on the username AS WELL AS the session id.

There are lots of solutions to this. I don't think any of them are exposed directly in Laravel.

You need to deal with maintaining the mapping directly in the session management - so you will need a custom session handler. The session handler deals with serialized data - so you need to think about how the username is resolved within the session handler. You could put it in the session and  deserialize the data again the handler, or read the value from a global variable. Or you could write a prototytype of the session into a database with the sessionid as the primary key and the username as an indexed lookup before the session close handler is called.

Another approach would be to store the session as the username rather than using the session id. You still need to protect the username though and avoid session fixation, hence you would need to explicity generate the session id using a mechansim where only you can recover the username from it, e.g.

```
 $data=array($username, openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
 $sessionid = encrypt(serialize($data), $your_secret_key);
```

(You still need to write your own session handler for this).